# SDP relaxation of mixed-integer nonlinear program

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, semidefinite-programming, relaxations

I am having trouble understanding the semidefinite programming (SDP) relaxation of a mixed-integer nonlinear program (MINLP) from section 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.11338). The optimization problem in MINLP form is

\begin{align}
\min_{x, y}{x^\intercal Qx}\\
\text{s.t. } \mu^\intercal x \geq \rho,\\
e^\intercal x \leq 1,\\
e^\intercal y \geq n - \aleph,\\
x_iy_i = 0,\ \forall\ i \in [n],\\
y_i \in \{0,1\},\\
0 \leq x_i \leq u_i,\ \forall\ i \in [n]
\end{align}

where $x, \mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $e$ is an $n$-dimensional vector of all 1's, $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\aleph \in \mathbb{N}$.

The authors relax this as an SDP, where they rewrite the objective function as $x^\intercal Q x = \langle{x, Qx}\rangle = \langle{Q, xx^\intercal}\rangle$ and introduce matrices $X \succcurlyeq xx^\intercal$ and $Y \succcurlyeq yy^\intercal$. Finally, using the Schur complement, they claim

$$
X \succcurlyeq xx^\intercal, Y \succcurlyeq yy^\intercal \iff \exists\ Z \in \mathcal{S}^n \text{ s.t. } \overline{X} \succcurlyeq 0,
$$

where

$$
\overline{X} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x^\intercal & y^\intercal\\
x & X & Z\\
y & Z^\intercal & Y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This then, somehow, leads to the following SDP relaxation of the above MINLP:

\begin{align}
\min_{\overline{X}}{\langle{Q, X}\rangle}\\
\text{s.t. } \mu^\intercal x \geq \rho,\\
e^\intercal x \leq 1,\\
e^\intercal y \geq n - \aleph,\\
\text{diag}(Z) = \mathbf{0},\\
\text{diag}(Y) = y\\
0 \leq x_i \leq u_i,\ \forall\ i \in [n],\\
\overline{X} \succcurlyeq 0.
\end{align}

I can reproduce this result **only** if we don't do the relaxation of $X \succcurlyeq xx^\intercal$ and $Y \succcurlyeq yy^\intercal$, but instead have $X = xx^\intercal, Y = yy^\intercal$, and also have $Z = xy^\intercal$, which would violate their claim of $Z$ being symmetric.

Am I missing something, or is this paper wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is a mistake in the paper. Matrix $Z$ is not symmetric.